# IBAction disabling not working

Tags: ios, button, timer, ibaction

If the user keeps clicking on button1 one or two , progress2.progress keeps increasing/decreasing on each click and progress1.progress keeps the same value until the user stops clicking. And in case he will surely lose , if he also keeps clicking nothing happens until he stops clicking. I don't want it to be that way since I want to hide/disable the buttons as soon as it's confirmed that he's losing to fix this issue. Any way to fix that?

Here is my .m :

```
#import "ViewController.h"



@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController






- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden { return YES; }

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    progress1.progress=arc4random() % 11 * 0.1;

    count1=0;
    count2=0;
    label1.hidden = NO;
    gameOver.hidden = YES;
    score=0;


    [super viewDidLoad];


    ;
}




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



-(void)regulator{
   if(timer1)
    {
        [timer1 invalidate];
        timer1 = nil;
    }

    if(timer4)
    {
        [timer4 invalidate];
        timer4 = nil;
    }

    timer4 =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5 target:self selector:@selector(conditioner) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];




       ;}


-(void)conditioner {
        if (fabs(progress2.progress-progress1.progress)<=0.25            )

        {
            score=score+1;
            scorenumber.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",score];
            [self newGame];
            ;
        } else{

            stop1=YES;
            stop2=YES;
            gameOver.hidden=NO;
            stick.hidden=YES;
            bg.hidden=YES;
            progress1.hidden=YES;
            progress2.hidden=YES;
            supply.hidden=YES;
            demand.hidden=YES;
        }}


-(void)newGame{




       progress1.progress=arc4random() % 11 * 0.1;}













- (IBAction)start:(UIButton *)sender {
    progress2.progress=arc4random() % 11 * 0.1;




   if(timer4)
    {
        [timer4 invalidate];
        timer4 = nil;


   timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(regulator) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



      [self regulator];
    stop1=NO;
    stop2=NO;
    label1.hidden=YES;

    UIButton *button1 = (UIButton *)sender;
    button1.enabled = NO;

    UIButton *button2 = (UIButton *)sender;
    button2.enabled = NO;



}






- (IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender {


    if(stop1==YES){button12.hidden = TRUE;}
    progress2.progress=progress2.progress-0.05;



                                       ;





    [self regulator];



    count2=0;
    count1 = count1 +1;




   }



- (IBAction)button2:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self regulator];

    progress2.progress=progress2.progress+0.05;

    if(stop2==YES){button22.hidden = TRUE;}



    count1 =0;
    count2 = count2+1;

   }



@end
```

and my .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int count1;
int count2;
int score;
void *regulator;
void *newGame;
void *conditioner;
BOOL stop1;
BOOL stop2;
void *firstLaunch;



@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UILabel *scorenumber;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *stick;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *bg;
    IBOutlet UILabel *supply;

    IBOutlet UILabel *demand;

    IBOutlet UILabel *gameOver;
    IBOutlet UIProgressView *progress1;

    IBOutlet UIProgressView *progress2;


    IBOutlet UIButton *button12;

    IBOutlet UIButton *button22;
    NSTimer *timer1;

    NSTimer *timer2;
    NSTimer *timer3;
    NSTimer *timer4;

   }

- (IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)button2:(UIButton *)sender;













    @end
```

Thanks a lot for any help or information. I edited my question with the full code to give further explanation about the issue I'm facing. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a coding issue. MVC basics.

I believe you miss some understanding of things. So I'll explain:

1. IBAction - It's an action sent from the view to the controller.
2. IBOutlet - Meant for the controller to control the view.

On your code you are getting the sender (which should be read only when coding right) and you are trying to set it up. I assume you need to define a new IBOutlet to represent the button then connect it on your storyboard and then inside this function to make it enable/disabled.

Also a good practice would be to use "TRUE" and "FALSE" and not "YES/NO".

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I try to do so , it says: Local declaration of 'button1' hides instance variable , same for button2.

Comment: Call the variable with different name :)

Comment: The error is gone. I set the buttons as hidden if the user is going to lose. However , if the user keeps clicking on button1 one or two , progress2.progress keeps increasing/decreasing on each click and progress1.progress keeps the same value until the user stops clicking. And in case he will surely lose , if he also keeps clicking nothing happens until he stops clicking. I don't want it to be that way since I want to hide/disable the buttons to fix this issue. Any way to fix that?

Comment: It's a different question, and it's hard to answer without to see all code. If this answer helps you please upvode. If you publish all relevant code I would take a look.

Comment: Please check the edited code and get back to me when you can.
I added the full code. Regards.

Comment: @Joseph I answered your original question (right now you changed it completely making stackoverflow and me look bad), so please accept the answer. This is not a good practice to put here general code question. I suggest you debug this one and put new question about the relevant issue you are troubling with. You have 2 timers that start from different places and being released from different functions. This looks pretty bad.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I'm new to both coding and stackoverflow.

Comment: Np, Just edit the question to what it was at first (so my answer would be relevant) and ask new question about the specific issue you have after debugging your code.
Btw, I would recommend learning swift and not ObjectiveC if you are starting iPhone development at this time.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can approach this to make sure when user touches the button then it doesn't do anything.

It wasn't clear from your question so I assume on touch down of button you call (IBAction)button1. So Try

```
- (IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender 
{


    if(stop1==YES)
    {
       //game has stopped so don't do anything
    }
    else
    {

      progress2.progress=progress2.progress-0.05;
      [self regulator];
    }


}
```

If you want to hide it so that the user can't do anything try this

```
- (IBAction)button1:(UIButton *)sender 
    {


        if(stop1==YES)
        {
           //game has stopped so hide this button
           //assuming you have connected an IBOutlet to your button1
           button1.hidden = YES;
        }
        else
        {
          button1.hidden = NO;
          progress2.progress=progress2.progress-0.05;
          [self regulator];
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I want the second option but when I connect an IBOutlet it says :  Local declaration of 'button1' hides instance variable , same for button2

Comment: If you defined UIButtons button1 and button2 in your *.h then remove the local declaration of it from your *.m file. i.e. remove UIButton *button1 = ... and change that to just button1 = ...